# Shopify form post to external url

Tags: forms, url, external, shopify

I have a site hosted with Shopify.  I would like to implement a form that posts to an external url.  This is a custom form.  My original thought is that I could just create a new page and add a form similar to these examples here - http://wiki.shopify.com/Contact_And_Signup_Forms#Signup_Forms

But, I don't see an option to post to an external url.  I am completely new to Shopify.  I had hoped that being a rails programmer would have helped, but it looks like I need to work with the liquid template system and not rails.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the liquid form tag, just use straight HTML and specify an action for your form that points to an external URL.

Example:

```
<form action="http://your-url.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email_address">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

The above example will POST to `http://your-url.com`.

Comment: This is an old one... and how does the form handle the response back from the third party API?